# NodeJS Docker current vs latest

Tags: node.js, docker

The [official Docker container for NodeJS](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) supports the tags "current" and "latest". What is the difference between those two? I have noticed that there is only a single "latest" but "current" comes with the usual suffixes (-slim, -alpine).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the difference is this:

The tag `latest` is kind of a Docker convention and should exist for every image in order to ease the use of the newest version. However, there is always only a single `latest` tag but the NodeJS image comes with various variants (alpine, debian, etc.) which obviously each all have a newest version. Hence, they decided to introduce the `current` tags which denote the latest image version of each of these different variants.

Also, AFAIK, `latest`, `current` and `current-buster` are the same image.